Allow modal window to scroll
I am having problems configuring my modal to allow scroll when content overflows. I tried adding "overflow: auto" to the modal, but it didn't work. Please, note that I am not using Bootstrap. I did add css to prevent the background from scrolling when the modal is open. That might be the reason why I can't scroll the modal. See below the css I am using.
#modal-background {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: var(--modal-background-color);
    opacity: .50;
    -webkit-opacity: .5;
    -moz-opacity: .5;
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
    z-index: 1000;
}

#modal-content {
    background-color: var(--modal-content-background-color);
    overflow: auto;
    border-radius: 10px;
    color: var(--modal-font-color);
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 #222;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 #222;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 #222;
    display: none;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    left: 50%;
    margin: -120px 0 0 -160px;
    padding: 10px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    z-index: 1000;
}

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

You've got height: auto in your modal-content which means the element will expand to fill the content. Set a max-height and it'll scroll when it reaches that height.

You can just set the max-height to a specified value, that way your content scrolls. As of right now, you have your height set to height: auto; which means your modal is always trying to have the max height the View Port can have.
